# "Working In Background" cursor while executing WritableStream.close() in chromium

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, chromium, file-system-access-api

We are developing a web tool to record Videos of the users screen and webcam.
Some people recording large videos longer than an hour. By using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) (in Chrome and Edge on Windows), we want to backup the recording Video to a file in the host's file system in case the browser or pc crashes.
All this is working like expected except of one side effect while closing the WritableStream (`WritableStream.close()`). While closing the Stream the cursor shortly changes system wide to the windows "Working In Background" Cursor.

[image: Working In Background Cursor Windows]

Does anyone know if there is any solution to prevent Chrome/Edge/Chromium from changing the cursor? Because we are recording the user's screen a cursor change every few seconds is not acceptable.

Example code:

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="selectDirectory()">Select Directory for Backup</button>

    <script>
        async function selectDirectory() {
            const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
            const fileHandle = await dirHandle.getFileHandle('backup.txt', { create: true });

            setInterval(async () => {
                const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
                await writable.write("Test");

                console.log('closing writeable...');
                await writable.close(); // at this point the cursor changes
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't reproduce on Chrome 95 on Mac with your sample code. An improvement would be to create the `writable` just once outside of the interval, and then close it once you're done (note that `write()` without further arguments always writes at the beginning of the file). Since it's essentially a `WritableStream`, you might also be able to `pipe()` to it as a further improvement.

Comment: No, this is not an option, because first the close method writes the written content to the file. Before closing, the data is written to a swap file, at least on Windows. But we need to write to the file and not to a swapfile every x seconds to create a safe backup.
And yes I know that this example always writes to the beginning of the file, it's just to keep it simple.